# I have a list of users, how do I change it to a drop-down (using Razor in MVC)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu

I am getting a list of my users using the below code:

Here is my view:

```
@model System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ManageProfile";
}
<div class ="hero-unit">
<h2>ManageProfile</h2>

<ul>
       @foreach (MembershipUser user in Model)
       {<li>@user.UserName</li>}

</ul>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
    public ActionResult ManageProfile()
    {
        var users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
        return View(users);
    }
```

I would prefer that I be able to select the user from a dropdown list.  How do I modify my code to yield a dropdown list?  (my goal is to be able to select the user from the dropdown list and change details of that user's profile)

Comment: I don't understand what would go where the ellipsis are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always in ASP.NET MVC application you could start by designing a view model that will meet the requirements of your view (which from what you described in your question is displaying a dropdownlist with all users):

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "select user")]
    public string SelectedUser { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Users { get; set; }
}
```

then you write a controller that will query your repositories and construct a view model that will be passed to the view:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Users = users.OfType<MembershipUser>().Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.UserName,
                Text = x.UserName
            })
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string selectedUser)
    {
        return Content("Thank you for selecting " + selectedUser);
    }
}
```

and finally you write a corresponding view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SelectedUser)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedUser, Model.Users)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Comment: @moguzalp, for me personally a view model is always practical. Even in small projects. Well, depends on your definition of small project of course.

Comment: @moguzalp I disagree with that.  ViewModels alleviate maintenance and maximize scalability.

Comment: This was a very clean solution for what I needed.  Thank you for the succinct reply and detailed explanation, actually (inadvertently) taught me something very specific and useful for another part of my project as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look into my answer in following post

[bind data to dropdownlist of partialview in MVC3 using viewbag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392883/bind-data-to-dropdownlist-of-partialview-in-mvc3-using-viewbag/9393133#9393133)

I have given an example how to use IEnumerable as a model property and assign values in controller and use in the view.(View uses Aspx View engine) for Razor try following

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedCountry,Model.countriesList)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedState,Model.stateList)
```

Comment: Seemed a little less elegant than what I was able to smoothly learn from, and Darin Dimitrov handled it so wonderfully.

Thank you for the assistance though.

Answer (score 0):

**Action Method**:

```
public ActionResult ManageProfile()
{
    List<SelectListItem> userNames = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var users = Membership.GetAllUsers();

    foreach (MembershipUser user in users)
        userNames.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = user.UserName, Value = user.UserName);

    return View(userNames);
}
```

**View**:

```
@model List<SelectListItem>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ManageProfile";
}
<div class ="hero-unit">
<h2>ManageProfile</h2>

@Html.DropDownList("SelectedUser", Model)

</div>
```

This is the simple, unscalable way that shows the idea of how to use `DropDownList()` (you could also use `DropDownListFor()`).  But I'd recommend constructing some sort of ViewModel to include this data, and then you would use a strongly-typed View with the ViewModel as the `@model`.